# How to get list of files using FileProvider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-fileprovider

A'm working on Android project.
I need to provide ContentProvider to provide access to some directory.
FileProvider it is good solution for me.
Is it possible to retrieve list of files in directory using FileProvider?

Comment: What have you tried? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html

Comment: Yes I tryed but there is only one sample how to get one file with specific name 'File imagePath = new File(Context.getFilesDir(), "images");
File newFile = new File(imagePath, "default_image.jpg");
Uri contentUri = getUriForFile(getContext(), "com.mydomain.fileprovider", newFile);' I need to fild the way to get full list of files in dirrectory

Answer (score 1):

User ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE to send multiple URI

```
// Set up an Intent to send back to apps that request files
mResultIntent = new Intent("com.yourpacakgename.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE");
// Get the files/res subdirectory;
File mResDir = new File(getFilesDir(), "res");
// Get the files in the res subdirectory
File[] mResFiles = mResDir.listFiles();
// Uri list
ArrayList<Uri> uriArrayList = new ArrayList<Uri>();
// Set the Activity's result to null to begin with
setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, null);

Uri fileUri = null;
for (int i = 0; i < mResFiles.length; i++) {
    Log.i(TAG, mResFiles[i].getName());
    // Use the FileProvider to get a content URI
    try {
        fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, this.getPackageName() + ".fileprovider", mResFiles[i]);
        // add current file uri to the list
        uriArrayList.add(fileUri);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "The selected file can't be shared: " + mResFiles[i].getPath());
        fileUri = null;
    }
}

if (uriArrayList.size() != 0) {
    // Put the UriList Intent
    mResultIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriArrayList);
    mResultIntent.setType("application/*");
    // Grant temporary read permission to all apps
    mResultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    // if you want send this to a specific app
    //grantUriPermission("pacakgename of client app", fileUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    // Set the result
    this.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, mResultIntent);
} else {
    // Set the result to failed
    mResultIntent.setDataAndType(null, "");
    this.setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, mResultIntent);
}
// Finish Activity and return Result to Caller
finish();
```